# sql: how to query foreign key not based upon ID

Tags: sql

My table IncomingLetter has a foreign key to a table Department, which has an `ID` and a column `Short_Name`.

I'm using this query to count the incoming letters assigned to a department.

```
SELECT COUNT(DocumentNumber) AS TotalNumberIncomingLetters
FROM IncomingLetter
WHERE Assigned_To_Department=1;
```

Whereas this works I want to make a query based upon the short name and not based upon the ID.

```
SELECT COUNT(DocumentNumber) AS TotalNumberIncomingLetters
FROM IncomingLetter
WHERE Assigned_To_Department.Short_Name="My Department Name";
```

This does not work, whereas I found examples that are using this syntax. However, it is probably important to notice, that I m using this query in MS access.

Comment: `Assigned_To_Department` is table or column ?

Comment: Assigned_To_Department is a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
SELECT COUNT(il.DocumentNumber) AS TotalNumberIncomingLetters
FROM IncomingLetter il
 INNER JOIN Department d on d.ID = il.Assigned_To_Department
WHERE d.Short_Name="My Department Name";
```

The "My Department Name" text is actually stored in the `Departments` table, and only the number (1) is stored in the `IncomingLetter` table, in the field `Assigned_To_Department`.
Asking for `Assigned_To_Department.Short_Name` basically asks the number 1 to get it's `Short_Name` field, that does not make sense.

You need to tell the database engine two things in these scenarios:

- which tables are connected - `IncomingLetter` and `Departments` in this case (the `inner join` part)
- how they are connected - by setting their `Assigned_To_Department` and `ID` fields respecively (the `on ...` part

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for including the explanation. Just perfect! Works like a charme.